# jquery datepicker textbox value issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts1

I have 2 text boxes namely fromDate & toDate for date search , in which by default, current day will be showed.

working code:

**Jquery**

```
(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dateClass').datetimepicker({timepicker: false}); // css for displaying date without time

    $('#fromDateId').datetimepicker({value: '01-01-2016', format: 'd-M-Y'});     // display current date with dd-mmm-yyyy        
    $('#toDateId').datetimepicker({value: '01-01-2016', format: 'd-M-Y'});       // display current date with dd-mmm-yyyy  
});
```

**Struts**

```
<html:text property="fromDate"  styleId="fromDateId" styleClass="dateClass"  />
<html:text property="toDate"  styleId="toDateId" styleClass="dateClass"  />
```

**Issue:**

By default current day shown in both textboxes, suppose user choose different dates and submit, 
 db records are fetched and displayed but these 2 texboxes replaced with current dates how to avoid this.

kindly help me to resolve.

Comment: Set to yesterday:

$('#date_pretty').datepicker('setDate', '-1');

Answer (score 0):

Update: There are reports this no longer works in Chrome.

This is concise and does the job:

```
$(".fromDateId").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

And another thing,

```
$(function()
{
    $('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
});
```